# Can a final class extend any other class? If so, then what is the use of the inheritance by a final class?

Tags: java, class, final

Can a `final` class extend any other class? If so, then what is the use of the inheritance by a `final` class?

`Final` class can't be *inherited* but is it possible to extend any other class by a `final` class?

Comment: `final` classes can extend any class, but can't be extended.

Comment: *"can final class extend any other class??"* - Yes, but itself can't be extended.  Try extending from `String`

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final classes are meant to be uninheritable. These classes are sealed from further extension by inheritance. final classes are used primarly to bring in immutability.

Comment: It isn't an answer to the question, this piece of information the original poster already knows.

Answer (score 2):

`final` classes can extend other classes but cannot be extended from. You cannot declare a class that extends from a final class.

`abstract` classes can only be extended by other classes and not used directly to create objects.